# "<" and ">" become "&gt;" and "&lt;" in requestdump ,How to avoid this situation when I want to transfer the xml format parameters

Tags: android-ksoap2

"<" and ">" become ">" and "<" in requestdump ,How to avoid this situation when I want to transfer the xml format parameters?

requestdump:

```
<aaa i:type="d:string">
&lt;Detect&gt;&lt;Target Tar="bbb" Points="5"&gt;&lt;Point x="306"  
y="63"/&gt;&lt;Point x="399" y="63"/&gt;&lt;Point x="399" y="261"/&gt;&lt;Point x="306"  `y="261"/&gt;&lt;Point x="306" y="63"/&gt;&lt;/Target&gt;&lt;/Detect&gt;

y="261"/&gt;&lt;Point x="306" y="63"/&gt;&lt;/Target&gt;&lt;/Detect&gt;
```

The format of the server-side requirements:

```
<aaa>
<Detect><Target Tar="bbb"><Point x="111" y="222"/><Point x="333" y="444" /><Point x="555" y="666"/></Target></Detect></aaa>
```

ps:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Html.fromHtml(respons).toString();
```